# Please help! CSS3 glowing transition problems

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to follow this tutorial because I like the effect so much.

> [CSS Text Glow on Hover with Transition Effects](http://www.icodeya.com/2012/08/css-text-glow-on-hover-with-transition.html)

But the problem is, I set the background color to white.

```
<style>
.text-glow-hover-with-delay{
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #fff;
transition: text-shadow 3s;
-moz-transition: text-shadow 3s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: text-shadow 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: text-shadow 3s; /* Opera */
}

.text-glow-hover-with-delay:hover{
text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
}
</style>

<div class="text-glow-hover-with-delay">
Put your mouse over me and I will glow slowly.
</div>
```

and now it doesn't glow anymore. I'm  noob on CSS here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are not able to see the shadow cause its white.
But, its working fine and smoothly. Just reduce the time, 3 seconds are too much.

[**Here is the working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZJD3/1/)

OR, if you just want a white shadow [**See Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZJD3/2/)

Comment: 어.. you're right! Ahh.. I failed to comprehend. Thank you. It's working good now.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the transition CSS as it seemed to be messing it up and I changed the color tpo black:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ce5SB/

Answer (score 0):

For css transitions you must go from point A to point B.

This means that point A should have a default text-shadow on your default class.

```
 .text-glow-hover-with-delay{
      text-shadow:0 0 0 #fff;/*This is the missing piece*/

      ....
 }
```

With the above missing piece, point B will know where to transition from.

also let me know if the above doesn't work.  You may also want to try the transition as

```
 transition:all 300ms ease;/*just in case each browser wants to capture its browser specific text shadow property*/
```